# Why is there a white screen after the Flutter keyboard is put away?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When I use Flutter, when the keyboard is closed, there will be a short white screen under the page before I can see the content.

Comment: add your code, so that please could help you.

Answer (score 4):

It's because the body of the `Scaffold` gets resized when you open the keyboard

You can avoid the resizing with `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` or use another `backgroundColor` on the `Scaffold`